# Заполнить поля виджета в Yii

Tags: поиск, php, yii

Виджет поиска расположен в layout. Так вот, при поиске происходит переход на другую страницу, но форма поиска обнуляется (значения полей исчезают). Как заставить поля сохранять значения?

Виджет

```
protected function renderContent()
{
    $this->render('_search',array(
        'model'=>Flats::model(),
        ));

}
```

Контроллер

```
public function actionSearch()
{
    $model=new Flats('search');
    $model->unsetAttributes();  // clear any default values
    if(isset($_GET['Flats']))
        $model->attributes=$_GET['Flats'];
    $this->render('search',array(
        'model'=>$model,
    ));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

попробуй в контроллере дополнительно засовывать переменные в Yii::app()->params[...], а в view( layout) сделай подстановку из этих значений(проверка на пустоту только нужна).

Comment: можно более подробно, не совсем понятно
может их можно с помощью $_GET как нибудь засунуть туда? сейчас попробовал такую же форму зарендерить на странице поиска, она заполнилась

Comment: Добавьте контроллеру аттрибут, например public $search = '';
  
В любом виджете вы сможете получить доступ к вызывающему его контроллеру через $this->controller->search

Comment: И как мне это использовать? Можно на конкретном примере? У меня в форме поиска полей - вагон.

Comment: Если еще актуально то примерно примерно такой:

Yii::app()->params = array('poisk'=>array('zanr' => $item)); # это в контроллере, в $item какая то категория которую ищет пользователь

 <?php if(isset(Yii::app()->params['poisk']['zanr'])):?><?php if(Yii::app()->params['poisk']['zanr'] == 'Аниме'):?> # это я делаю активной категорию на view (layout) 

Вы можете хранить там целый массив значений.